# Import file every hour

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import

I'm looking at using an import file activity on marketing cloud - the file pattern we usually use is %%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%nameoffile.csv. This time we want the import to run hourly not daily.

If we are creating an Import file to run hourly (new file every hour)- **Will we have to create a new file name pattern and include %%hour%%?strong text**

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted, if it was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with keeping the **%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%nameoffile.csv** naming convention. What will happen is, the files will be overwritten for each hourly upload, but the import into Marketing Cloud will still function correctly. So the records will always be upserted based on the rows in the latest file uploaded within that particular day.

The only drawback would be, your inability to store historical files in the FTP folder, to validate the data inserted matches the data in your files.